# How to smoothly animate the hiding of the toolbar plus something below it.

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I am using the appcompat toolbar as my action bar and I have a layout right below it with some more views, it is roughly the same height as the toolbar.

I am hiding both of those together when scrolling happens on the main view  of the activity (which is below them) and it is working well but the hiding is too abrupt and I would like to make it happen smoothly. I have seen a lot of posts about how to do that to the toolbar but I haven't found any for hiding the toolbar and something below it, so how to I smoothly hide and show both?

Essentially what I have is this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar .../>
<RelativeLayout .../>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use alpha animation with translationY animation on toolbar 
For  i.e

```
                view.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(1).setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

For  more info please refer google 
[Ioschedule](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched) app source code.

Comment: I'll try that in a bit but won't that animate the hide/show per view and I am hiding two separate views so is it going to look weird?

Answer (score 3):

i have found this link on github [HideOnScroll](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample) you can read about this repository by the author who has given nice explanation on how to hide toolbar here is the other link [Blog Link](http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/)